# Create a batch file to run cmd commands

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to create a batch or is it a bat file? to start cmd and run 2 commands, namely:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=myssidhere key=password
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

and close when complete, any ideas please?

Thanks in advance

Martin

Comment: What is your question? (I don't think it matters much whether you call it a batch or a bat file.)

Comment: You're in luck! A batch file is (for lack of a better term) just a text file with cmd commands in it that you give a .bat extension. Just stick those two commands in a file, give it the .bat extension, and double-click it! (Also, batch scripts generally start with the line `@echo off` as well.)

Comment: Just shows how thick i am :/ lol 
Is there a command to close the cmd when finished, i have tried a few, such as, exit, exit /b ect, cls works but it starts another cmd with just netsh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open notepad and create a text file (with .bat extension) with the following content:

```
@ECHO off
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=myssidhere key=password
netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Notepad++ or something and use this:

`@echo off
echo Start netsh
echo.
echo Press any button.
pause >nul
netsh wlan set hostednetwrok mode=allow ssid=mssidhere key=password
netshwlan start hostednetwork
echo.
echo Done. 
pause >nul`

Save it as

> nameitanything.bat

---

I added pauses to ensure that you don't run it accidental at times.

Comment: Thats spot on, working great, thank you ever so much :)

Comment: Anytime, glad to help :)